Finding the Constant Term of a Binomial Expansion.
I am trying to find the constant term of the binomial: $$(2x+3x^{-2})^9$$
The first thought I had was to simplify this into $(2x^9+3x^{-18})$ which can then be expressed as:
$\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{9}$ $^9$$C$$_r$$2x^{9-r}$$(3x^{-18})^r$
Then simplified to. $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{9}$$^9$$C$$_r$$2x^{-19r+9}$$(3)^r$.
I am struggling trying to find a way to then equate this to $x^0$ to find the constant term. Maybe $2x^{-19r+9}(3)^r$ simplified into $2x^{-10r}(3)^r$ then $\frac{2x3^r}{x^{10r}}$ I am unsure of how to solve for $r$ in this scenario.

Can you explicitly show the working of the "This can then be expressed as .." and "simplified to ...." ? There's are errors in there, which could be a lack of understanding or a typo. (I can't tell which, hence the request for you to state your thinking)

@CalvinLin In all honesty it's due to a lack of understanding which I hope to improve here. I was using the formula $(a+b)^n$=$\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{n}$$^n$$C$$_r$$a^{n-r}b^r$ & input the exponent of 9 & values from the binomial. I'm thinking maybe I should not have tried to simplify the binomial before making the summation, I have never done this with nested exponents before & wasn't sure what to do with them. The simplification was done to raise a product to a power by raising all factors to that power & then calculating that product.

So it seems to me that you made numerous mistakes of understanding (as opposed to just a typo), so I would encourage you to write this out again, to ensure you know what should be done. This is why I asked you to show your work, with the hope that you could have spotted the mistakes.

Your expression can be written as
$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{9} \binom{9}{r} (2x)^{9-r} (3x^{-2})^r$$
$$ = \sum\limits_{r=0}^{9} \binom{9}{r} 2^9 \left( \frac32 \right)^{r} x^{9-3r}$$
To get the $x^{0}$ terms, $9-3r=0$. i.e. $r=3$.
So you get the constant term as $2^6 3^3 \binom{9}{3} = 145152$

I just have one question how come $2^9$ becomes $2^6$?

Sorry, I should have shown explicitly. $2^9 \left(  \frac32\right)^3 = 2^{9-3} 3^3 = 2^6 3^3$

You have made an analytical mistake.
In general, $~(a + b)^n \neq a^n + b^n.$
So
$$\left( ~2x + 3x^{-2} ~\right)^9 \neq 2x^9 + \left(3x^{-2}\right)^9.$$
In my opinion, the easiest way to both expand the intuition of the OP (i.e. original poster) and solve the problem analytically is as follows:
Consider the following tableau of factors, which represents
$$\left( ~2x + 3x^{-2} ~\right)^9.$$
2x + 3x^{-2}
2x + 3x^{-2}
2x + 3x^{-2}
2x + 3x^{-2}
2x + 3x^{-2}
2x + 3x^{-2}
2x + 3x^{-2}
2x + 3x^{-2}
2x + 3x^{-2}

When you multiply these $~9~$ factors together, with each factor, you will have a choice of whether to select the left term or the right term.  So, from a crude viewpoint, you will have $~2^9~$ different terms, which can be grouped by the exponent assigned to the variable $~x.~$
Then, the problem reduces to determining how many of these $~2^9~$ terms will belong to the group that corresponds to $~x^0,~$ and what the sum of all of the terms in this group will be.
In the tableau, the only way to create a term that is assigned to the $~x^0~$ group is to combine $~6~$ of the $~2x~$ terms with $~3~$ of the $~3x^{-2}~$ terms.
There are then $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{6}~$ ways of selecting the $~6~$ $~2x~$ terms, with the remaining $~3~$ terms corresponding to the $~3x^{-2}.$
Therefore, the final computation is
$$\binom{9}{6} \times 2^6 \times 3^3.$$

@CalvinLin "The first thought I had was to simplify this into $(2x^9+3x^{-18})$" : I can only interpret this in one way.  It is then reasonable for me to presume that any subsequent analysis that they have, while quite possibly being more accurate, is pointless for me to try to wade through.  That is, once the OP demonstrates such underlying confusion, I regard it as game over.

Ah! I didn't even see that and just glossed over it because they did the expansion thereafter. Oh wow, this is just wrong on so many levels. Agree with you.
